Why doesn't the integration on page 58 in Concepts in Thermal Physics by Blundell and Blundell undercount molecules?
I was just reading page 58 in Concepts in Thermal Physics by Blundell and Blundell, and I got this question. They write that the volume swept out is $(A \cdot dt \cdot v \cdot \cos \theta)$, but I think there are also other molecules that fly at the angle $\theta$, like I painted on the screenshot in red. What am I wrong about?


The calculation is correct, but I think it is conceptually easier to do the integration over $\phi$ after constructing the diagram, not before as Blundells (and many other authors) do it. That way you can be sure you got the shape and its volume right.

There are, as you imply, directions of travel at $\theta$ to the normal all round the normal. These are all taken into account in the 'solid angle' ($\Omega$) treatment at the top of the page you have copied. The shaded volume at the bottom of the page is representative of any and all of these angles $\theta$. Hence Blundell can – and does – multiply the number obtained from the top argument by the shaded volume.
